# Getting Location updates only from Apple Watch (even when an iPhone is connected)

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

Is it possible to always use the GPS chip in the Apple Watch for a WatchKit app, even when a iPhone is connected  (for Apple Watch series 2 and above because these models have a GPS chip on board).

For my app on watchOS I need the most accurate GPS data. Unfortunately, when an iPhone is connected location request (using the standard code) are delegated to the iPhone and the GPS chip of the iPhone is used. This makes perfectly sense from a power conservation perspective, but not from an accuracy perspective. The iPhone could be tucked away in a coat, bag etc. In that case the phone has no clear view to the sky, while the watch has. The GPS data from the watch are much, much more accurate in that case (and the iPhone GPS data extremely inaccurate)

Is there a way to configure the CLLocationManager to block delegation of GPS location requests to the iPhone and always use the GPS chip in the watch?

Comment: Wow, never knew this. Hmm... you could try disabling location updates in phone app background modes and seeing if the watch still gets updates while the phone is backgrounded.

Comment: @Myk Yeah, was pretty surprised to find this out while testing the app. It isn’t documented anywhere but evidence that this is designed this way could be found here https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/716/?time=1792 . I don’t think playing with the iPhone counterpart app will change this. Nevertheless, I will give it a shot. Thanks